# How To Get User Name From Facebook Unity SDK

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api

I am new in unity and trying to integrate Facebook unity SDK. But i am not able to find current logged-in user name. It will return only userId and accessToken. How to get login name after `FB.Login("email")`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you login, you can get the name with:

```
FB.API("me?fields=name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, <your callback here>);
```

Answer (score 3):

After calling the API

```
FB.API("me?fields=name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, NameCallBack);
```

get the exact name from the JSON like this:

```
void NameCallBack(FBResult result)
{
    IDictionary dict = Facebook.MiniJSON.Json.Deserialize(result.Text) as IDictionary;
    string fbname = dict["name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: the type FBResult not found!

Comment: @Ahmed Mohsen Unity and FB sdk versions? Are you using soomla?

Comment: I am using the newest FB SDK version now , and still FBResult type not found

Comment: @AhmedMohsen Using soomla?

Comment: NO , but in the newest SDK version . I should use IGraphResult instead of FBResult , and it works now

Comment: @AhmedMohsen Oh good! You may update the answer mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess if I was to look somewhere is to make use of that userId and FQL to query Facebook for the name of the user.

For instance using the Graph API Explorer: 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

I used the following query:

```
Select name from user where uid = [userId]
```

It returned the following JSON string:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "myName"
    }
  ]
}
```

I think you can use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/profilewithfql/ to get an idea of how to query the FB.API to perform a FQL query.

FQL Guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/